# TrackRevisions: Table with original and final text

Tags: vba, ms-word, revision

I am quite new to vba and I need to write a script that has as input a document with some revisions. For each paragraph i would like to have in a table the original text (no revisions) and the final text (as if all revisions have been accepted). If this is to difficult I would like to at least have a table that contains the new text, the number of the paragraph in the original document and the number of the paragraph in the final version

Here an example of how could look like the input of the script

[image]

Here what i would like to have as output

[image]

Here what I have been able to do. I am not able to get the original text and in case of multiple phrases insertion the script is able to recognize only the first one as new line.
The script go through all the paragraph, if the paragraph contains no revision just the text is added in the table. If the text contains at list one revision all except the last revision are accepted and if the last the revision is an insert then if the paragraph text before and after all revisions have been accepted is the same the next paragraph is considered as new line. If the last revision is a delete then if the paragraph text before all revisions have been accepted is equal to the text of reviosion the text paragraph is considered as interely deleted.

```
Sub TrackchangesTable()

    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oNewDoc As Document
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oRow As Row
    Dim oCol As Column
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim oRevision As Revision
    Dim strText As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Dim NewLine As Boolean
    Dim DraftText As String
    Dim NewId As Long
    Dim OldId As Long
    Dim OldText As String
    Dim Stile As String
    Dim OriginalDoc As Document
    
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

    
    If oDoc.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The active document contains no tracked changes.", vbOKOnly, Title
        GoTo ExitHere
    Else
        If MsgBox("Do  you want to extract tracked changes to a new document?" & vbCr & vbCr & , _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion) <> vbYes Then
            GoTo ExitHere
        End If
    End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add
    oNewDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    With oNewDoc
        .Content = ""
        With .PageSetup
            .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
            .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
        End With

        Set oTable = .Tables.Add _
            (Range:=Selection.Range, _
            numrows:=1, _
            NumColumns:=7)
    End With
    
            
    With oNewDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 9
            .Bold = False
        End With
        With .ParagraphFormat
            .LeftIndent = 0
        End With
    End With
    
    With oTable
        .Range.Style = wdStyleNormal
        .AllowAutoFit = False
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        .PreferredWidth = 100
        For Each oCol In .Columns
            oCol.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        Next oCol
        .Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 5  'Page
        .Columns(2).PreferredWidth = 5  'Note
        .Columns(3).PreferredWidth = 10 'Final Text
        .Columns(4).PreferredWidth = 15 'Inserted/deleted text
        .Columns(5).PreferredWidth = 15 'Old Id
        .Columns(6).PreferredWidth = 10 'New ID
        .Columns(7).PreferredWidth = 10 'Stile
    End With

    With oTable.Rows(1)
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Page"
        .Cells(2).Range.Text = "Note"
        .Cells(3).Range.Text = "Final Text"
        .Cells(4).Range.Text = "Deleted Text"
        .Cells(5).Range.Text = "Old Id"
        .Cells(6).Range.Text = "New Id"
        .Cells(7).Range.Text = "stile"
    End With
    
    NewLine = False
    OldId = 1
    NewId = 1
    
    For Each Para In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
        Stile = Para.Range.Style
        If Para.Range.Revisions.Count = 0 And NewLine = False Then
            StrTextFinale = Para.Range.Text
        ElseIf Para.Range.Revisions.Count = 0 And NewLine = True Then
            StrTextFinale = Para.Range.Text
            Note = "New Line"
            NewLine = False
            OldId = OldId - 1
        ElseIf Para.Range.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To Para.Range.Revisions.Count
                If i < Para.Range.Revisions.Count Then
                    Para.Range.Revisions(i).Accept
                Else
                    If Para.Range.Revisions(i).Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
                        DraftText = Para.Range.Text
                        Para.Range.Revisions(i).Accept
                        StrTextFinale = Para.Range.Text
                        If DraftText = StrTextFinale Then
                            NewLine = True
                        End If
                    ElseIf Para.Range.Revisions(i).Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
                        DraftText = Para.Range.Revisions(i).Range.Text
                        StrTextFinale = Para.Range.Text
                        If DraftText = StrTextFinale Then
                            Note = "Testo eliminato"
                            StrTextFinale = "volutamente cancellato"
                            OldText = Para.Range.Text
                            NewId = NewId - 1
                        Else
                            Para.Range.Revisions(i).Accept
                            StrTextFinale = Para.Range.Text
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        
        Set oRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    
        With oRow
            .Cells(1).Range.Text = Para.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            .Cells(2).Range.Text = Note
            .Cells(3).Range.Text = StrTextFinale
            .Cells(4).Range.Text = OldText
            .Cells(5).Range.Text = OldId
            .Cells(6).Range.Text = NewId
            .Cells(7).Range.Text = Stile
            Note = ""
        End With
    OldId = OldId + 1
    NewId = NewId + 1
    OldText = ""
    Next
    

    With oTable.Rows(1)
        .Range.Font.Bold = True
        .HeadingFormat = True
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenRefresh
        
    MsgBox ("Over")

    ExitHere:
        Set oDoc = Nothing
        Set oNewDoc = Nothing
        Set oTable = Nothing
        Set oRow = Nothing
        Set oRange = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me to improve this script?

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/133132-post2.html. The code there is far more comprehensive than what you have in mind, though it doesn't report what the unrevised content was. In any event, I doubt you'd really want to get half-page paragraphs of original & changed content when only a single word in the paragraph was changed - or no changes were made. All that does is add clutter. You may also be interested in: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/export-comments-with-referred-text-and-line-numbers-from-word-to-excel.1120281/post-5407348

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. The script you sent me is able to export to an excel files almost all the revisions giving additional information as author, page, date, etc...
But what i need to do is a little different. I have a document inserted in a tool, the later the document has been modified and i want to update the document uploaded in the tool but i want to do that automatically. So I need to know the relationship betwwen the 2 version of the same document

Comment: «I have a document inserted in a tool, the later the document has been modified and i want to update the document uploaded in the tool but i want to do that automatically» Kindly update your question to include *all* the relevant details, including what the 'tool', and what is supposed to happen when multiple edits have been made to the same range. It's also not apparent how you would handle a paragraph being moved from one location to another, potentially with additional edits as well.